# JavaScript DOM manipulation to make tab responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, dom

```
   <section class="tab-buttons tab container" id="tab-buttons">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'panel-1')">
        Fact Sheets
      </button>
      <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'panel-2')">
        Videos
      </button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'panel-3')">
        Images
      </button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'panel-4')">
        Reports
      </button>
    </section>
```

[image]

This is the tab bar that I created, I wanted to make this tab break into two or more tabs and each tab contain only two items if it on a mobile device, How can I do that using javascript dom manipulation, I'll add the image below, this is how I wanted to be on a mobile device,

[image]

Comment: This is typically available through CSS and does not need any Javascript DOM manipulation. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp
If you are using a UI library like bootstrap or Ionic it should provide you ready samples to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use media query in css for max-width-768px